# Form shown by jquery toggle not working

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem while using jQuery.

I made a login page that shows a small div for signup. This div is hidden by default and I'm using jQuerys toggle method to show it when signup button is clicked.

The problem is when this form shows up, clicking the submit button doesn't do anything (doesn't send a POST request)

```
<div id='signup-box' >
  <form method="post">
      <p>Name:
      <input type="text" name="username" value=""></p>
      <p>Password:
      <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Signup"/></p>
  </form>
</div>


$('#show-signup-form').on('click', function(){
    $('#signup-box').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

P.S. If I change `id` of form it is shown always and works very well.

Comment: Try to set `<div id='signup-box' >` to `<div id="signup-box" >` - double quotes instead of single quotes :) - I guess, jQuery does not recognize your ID :)

Comment: @StefanBrendle It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I confirmed. That's not the problem. The div shows and hides fine but submit button is not working.

Comment: Action-Tag is missing? Try to add `action="url"` to your form?

Comment: @stefan  Since POST data is sent to same file, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, I always thought, the tag has to be empty, if the data should be sent to the same file, like `action=""` ... but thank you for the explanation, I have never try it by just remove the whole action tag ...